# Design Pattern: how to decide the pattern of q/a race game

Tags: java, design-patterns

I am designing a race game. There is a list of question each user needs to answer in this game.

I have two types of questions. The first one is multiple choice question. This question contains a list of choice, and each choice is a String.

The other is searching question. This type of question has only one correct answer, which is type of Country. We will display a map and let user to find the correct country.

> ```
> public class Country {
>     String countryName;
>     LatLng ll;
> }
> ```

These two types of questions will be mixed together and display as a list to each user.

If the question displayed to user is a multiple choice questions, we will show a list of choices and let user to select;
If user sees a searching question, then s/he is required to search the corresponding country on a map.

There are two types of answer here, String and Country.

Here are my questions:

1. Should I design two type classes for each question, MCQuestion and SearchingQuestion, and let them extend the same abstract class Question?

> ```
> public abstract class Question {
>     String questionText;
>
> }
> ```

How to design each type of question. I need methods to return the correct answer and check whether one input is correct or not?

2. Should I also design two types answer for each type of answer?

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: I have a question field, and people needs to answer question. If this is a MCQ, then we have 4 options to let user to choose. If it is a searching question, then we will display a map and let user to find the correct country.

Comment: What benefit do you expect from deriving these completely different types of questions from the same abstract class?

Answer (score -1):

I think your overall approach makes sense.

Deriving the questions from one superclass is useful, because then you can for example store them in a `Questions[]` Array and pick a random one.

I don't know if you need two different answer types, because your answer basically consists of a String, whether it's one of `{"A","B","C","D"}` or a standard country code (which you could create a converter for to convert a country code in one of your `Country` Objects.)

Methods for getting and setting correct answer etc. are good, but we can't tell you what methods you need since only you know what the game will be like. If you are unsure, use MVC pattern. Your questions classes should only represent the model.